# Titan graph DB, Java exception during a query using external index ( Elasticsearch )

Tags: graph, groovy, indexing, titan

I have a tiny graph DB, 400k nodes and 150k Edges.

I was following the **"Type Definition Overview"** and **"Indexing Backend Overview"** directions to create keys, external indexes and query them, I've done:

**g.makeKey('State').dataType(String.class).indexed('dev-titan', Vertex.class).make();**

'dev-titan' = Elasticsearch index name

And I can find the states values in elasticsearch, titan index, under a field name "4O".

When I run this query, after 20 minutes or more I got this

rexster[groovy]> g=rexster.getGraph('graph')
==>titangraph[cassandra:xx.xx.x.xxx]

**rexster[groovy]> g.query().has("State",EQUAL,"TN").vertices()**

Mar 13, 2014 5:10:58 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain execute
WARNING: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tinkerpop.rexster.protocol.msg.ErrorResponseMessage cannot be cast to org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.WritableMessage
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:652)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:533)
        at com.tinkerpop.rexster.client.RexProClientFilter.handleRead(RexProClientFilter.java:155)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:815)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:567)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:547)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Standard indexes work good.

What I can be doing wrong?

I appriciate any help

Comment: Are you using an external ElasticSearch configuration?  Is that the error that appears in Rexster Console or the server logs?  If that is not the server log, please take a look in there to see if there's anything else that might be helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look to this. I'm using rexster console with external Elasticsearch.

Comment: Also note that you should use CONTAINS instead of EQUAL (For exact matches use a Titan index). However, that doesn't explain, why the query doesn't work at all. Another stacktrace from the server logs would be really helpful.

Comment: I am getting the same issue on titan 0.4.2. I'm not using any EQUAL. Does anyone know what else might be causing this?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. If I run in debug mode and have the debugger stop on the exception, I see that the error message was: org.msgpack.unpacker.SizeLimitException: Size of array (12271) over limit at 4096. So it seems there is a limit somewhere that the code doesn't handle properly.

Comment: ... and using the new msgpack jar mentioned  in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/9fqT8rd1ASo fixed my issue.